# PHImageManager requestImageData consumes a lot of memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory, out-of-memory, phimagemanager

I am using the following code to request image data

```
PHCachingImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { (imageData, _, _, _) in
                    guard let imageData = imageData,
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                        return
                    }
                    //Do something with image
                }
```

When the image size is around 15-20 mb the memory consumption of app increases by 50-60mb. I confirmed the same using instruments.

Then I tried using requestImage(for:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:) method which indeed reduces the memory consumption but the quality of image is really bad.

Is there any way to use requestImageData keep the memory consumption to be as low as possible since the images I am selecting may go to 50mb.